# shiny throws error while loading excel files when csv file is supposed to be loaded

Tags: r, shiny

I have designed a tool using shiny which ask user to upload either a csv or xlsx file designed through radiobutton. Now there are four conditions

1. He chooses csv and uploads a csv file, which is correct
2. choose xlsx and uploads a xlsx file, also correct
3. choose csv and uploads an xlsx file, this is incorrect
4. choose xlsx and uploads csv file also incorrect

Now for point 3 and 4, i check if there is any mismatch and if it is then warn user to reload correct file type. However point 4 is not getting detected and the tools through its own error.

ui code

```
library(shiny)
library(xlsx)
library(tools)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel("fileinput"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  radioButtons("filetype", "Select file type",choices=c("csv file","xlsx file")),
  fileInput("file1","upload",accept = c("text/csv","text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv",".xlsx",".xls"))

  ),
  mainPanel(
  uiOutput("Image_Data")
  )
  )
  )
  )
```

server code

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
# loading data
data <- reactive({
if(input$filetype=="xlsx file"){
  inFile <- input$file1
  if (is.null(inFile))
    return(NULL)
  a<-read.xlsx(inFile$datapath, sheetIndex=1,header =TRUE)
  as.data.frame(a)
  }else{
  inFile <- input$file1
  if (is.null(inFile))
    return(NULL)
  a<-read.csv(inFile$datapath,header =TRUE,stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  as.data.frame(a)
  }})
# info of the file
output$about_file<-renderTable({
input$file1})
# to display data
output$display <- renderDataTable({
data()})
# passing to UI finally
output$Image_Data<-renderUI({
if(is.null(data())){
h1("forecasting tool")
}
else if(input$filetype=="csv file" & input$file1$type != "text/csv"){
sprintf("reload correct file type")}
else if(input$filetype=="xlsx file" & input$file1$type != 
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"){
  sprintf("reload correct file type")}
  else if(input$filetype=="xlsx file" & input$file1$type != 
                                             "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"){
sprintf("reload correct file type")
}else{
tabsetPanel(tabPanel("DATA",dataTableOutput("display")), 
           tabPanel("aboufile", tableOutput("about_file")))
  }})})
```

I do have java 64 bit installed which is required to work with excel file in r.

Comment: Would it not be easier to bring the file name in as a text string and check the extension, then load based on the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are reading the file before you check for datatyp. Try to check the file ending before you read the files.

for example you could check if a file is an excel file with something like this

```
regexpr("\\.xlsx",input$file1) != -1
```

Comment: @ Bertil  else if(input$filetype=="xlsx file" & input$file1$type != 
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"){
  sprintf("reload correct file type")} has been replaced with else if(regexpr("\\.xlsx",input$file1$type) != -1){sprintf("reload correct file type")} but still throwing same error as earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was a basic lack of RnD from my end.

Issue is not with shiny but read.xlsx.

read.xlsx will not load any other file type other than xlsx and therefore throws error whereas read.csv will not throw any error(it gives warning) and load other type(xlsx) although the loaded file becomes irrelevant post loading.

what i did was just used tryCatch function and modified else if accordingly.
Below is the corrected code of server.r

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
# loading data
data <- reactive({
if(input$filetype=="xlsx file"){
  inFile <- input$file1
  if (is.null(inFile))
    return(NULL)
  a<-tryCatch(read.xlsx(inFile$datapath, sheetIndex=1,header =TRUE),error = function(e) return("wrong"))
  as.data.frame(a)
}else{
  inFile <- input$file1
  if (is.null(inFile))
    return(NULL)
  a<-read.csv(inFile$datapath,header =TRUE,stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  as.data.frame(a)
}})
# info of the file
 output$about_file<-renderTable({
          input$file1})
 # to display data
 output$display <- renderDataTable({
 data()})
# passing to UI finally
output$Image_Data<-renderUI({
if(is.null(data())){
  h1("forecasting tool")
}else if(input$filetype =="csv file" & input$file1$type != "text/csv"){

  h4(br(),br(),"Mismatch in formats of file selected and uploaded!!",style = "color: red;")


}else if(length(data())==1){
  #h4(br(),br(),"Mismatch in formats of file selected and uploaded!",style = "font-style: italic;font-weight: bold;color: red;text-align: center;")
  h4(br(),br(),"Mismatch in formats of file selected and uploaded!",style = "color:red")
  #sprintf("testing")
}else{
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel("DATA",dataTableOutput("display")), 
              tabPanel("aboufile", tableOutput("about_file")))
}})})
```